# How to switch CurrentCulture of MainThread from async context?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, culture, executioncontext

I have an old API with switches the current culture in that way:

```
private void ChangeCulture(int lcid)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"[{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] ChangeCulture Culture Start: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture}");

        var newCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lcid);

        Debug.WriteLine($"[{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] Changing culture of currentThread to: {newCulture}");

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;

        // Old framework compatibility (not important for this example)
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = newCulture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = newCulture;

        Debug.WriteLine($"[{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] ChangeCulture Culture End: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture}");
    }
```

Previously, the code was called from a synchronous context. However, since it is now required that the code is called from an asynchronous context. Like here:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"[{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}]Culture Start: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture}");
        if (this.currrentLcid == 1031)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            this.ChangeCulture(1033);
            this.currrentLcid = 1033;
        }
        else
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            this.ChangeCulture(1031);
            this.currrentLcid = 1031;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine($"[{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}]Culture End: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture}");
    }
```

Output:

```
[1]Culture Start: de-DE
[1] ChangeCulture Culture Start: de-DE
[1] Changing culture of currentThread to: en-US
[1] ChangeCulture Culture End: en-US
[1]Culture End: en-US
```

The culture flow with the async execution. But it doesn't flow globally back. If i call:

```
    private void CheckCulture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"[{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}]CheckCulture_Click: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture}");
    }
```

Output:

```
[1]CheckCulture_Click: de-DE
```

Everything is MainThread. (ManagedThreadId=1)

.NET Framework 4.8

How can i switch the current culture globally without knowledge of the calling context?

Comment: What is the expected outcome when clicking the `CheckCulture` button?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes, en-US. it was the last set culture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET Core these properties are implemented as `AsyncLocal<T>`'s which in short means that any updates to them only affect the current asynchronous control flow, such as an `async` method.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you may consider to create and set your own static `CultureInfo` properties.

On .NET Framework 4.6 and later, you could set the `NoAsyncCurrentCulture` switch to `true` in your `App.config` to get back the old behaviour:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup> 
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Globalization.NoAsyncCurrentCulture=true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

[<AppContextSwitchOverrides> element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/appcontextswitchoverrides-element?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077)

[Retargeting Changes for Migration from .NET Framework 4.5 to 4.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.5-4.6?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077)

Comment: I had already tried the flag, but set it by code (in the Application_Startup). Somehow this did not work. When I set it via App.config it seems to work. Thanks. Now I have to think about whether this flag is the right solution, but that's how it is, decisions are sometimes hard.

Comment: Maybe it is better if I switch the culture in a dispatcher.invokeAsync In relation to this sentence: Apps affected by this change may work around it by explicitly setting the desired System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture or System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture as the first operation in an async Task